# Boundedness of a function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I consider this function of $z=x+iy$ with $y>0$:
$$f(z)=\bigg|\frac{1}{\alpha-i{z}}\bigg|$$
with $\alpha> 0$ ($\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$).
Is it bounded?
making calculation we have
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\alpha+y)^2+x^2}}$$
What estimations can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's let $\alpha-iz=\beta$. Then because the norm of a complex number is multiplicative, we have
$$
|\beta^{-1}|\cdot|\beta|=1\implies|\beta^{-1}|=|\beta|^{-1}.
$$
We know what range of values $|\beta|$ can take. How can this help you?

Edit given your latest edits: fix $\alpha>0$. Then the denominator of $f(z)$ is bounded below by $\sqrt{(\alpha+y)^2}>\alpha$. Thus, to my thinking, $|f(z)|\leq 1/\alpha$.

Comment: I don't really understand your reasoning; is your a hint or a question?

Comment: It's a hint. I'll edit it.

Comment: With my restrictions $|\beta|=0$ is impossible (I've edited the question because I forgot to underline the positiveness of $\alpha$ and the fact that it is real)

Comment: If I consider $\alpha<0$ I have a problem in $z=-i\alpha$.
If I consider the function in the set of $z$ such as $y>0$ and $\Im z^2\neq 0$ I have boundedness again. Is so according to you too?

Comment: If $\alpha<0$, then we may let $z=\varepsilon-i\alpha$. Then
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\alpha-\alpha)^2+\varepsilon^2}}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}.
$$
For any $M\in\mathbb R$, if we let $\varepsilon=1/(M+1)$, then $f(\varepsilon-i\alpha)>M$. Thus $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: Yes you have reason. I can have boundedness for every real $\alpha\neq 0$ considering $z$ with real part in $[a,b]$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're driving at.

Comment: I want boundedness for $f(z)$; one possible way is considering the function defined in the set $\{z|\Re z\in [a,b]\}$.

Comment: What's this fraktur $R$ you mean?

Comment: With $\Re z$ I mean the real part of $z$

Comment: Uh, yeah. Okay. So if you want to bound $f$ then you're going to need to bound the real part of $z$ away from $0$.